# JS: Storing dynamic variables across pages?

Tags: javascript, jquery, forms

I've been looking into local storage options and plugins like Persist.js, sessvars.js, and even sisyphus.js - but I am unsure if any are the best fit (though I'm fairly certain I need to use one).

Page one is a form with input fields for data like names, phones, and email. I have a button that replicates a wrapper div (and it's inputs) as long as more inputs are needed. When the form is filled the user hits submit which takes them to a 'confirmation' type php page. I need to the give the user an 'edit' button on page 2 that takes them back to page 1 and leaves all the info alone.

For the most part everything returns fine, but if the user had hit the 'replicate' button before submission, and then hits edit afterwards, all the inputs that were dynamically generated return empty and the div no longer exists. Someone suggested that my variables are not persistent (when the replicate button is hit, input with an id="name1" becomes "name2" and so on) so that's when I found out about the plugins mentioned before.

Is there a way that I can implement one of those plugins (or any other method) so that when the user returns to page one the div and it's input values remain unchanged? And if I'm on the right track are there any examples?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Welcome to stackoverflow! I don't really know about those plugins, but at the low level they are probably using localStorage or sessionStorage (that I think is better for your problem, as it gets cleared everytime you restart the browser, opposed to localStorage, that is permanent unless the user clears it).

Your problem has a pretty easy solution, although I don't understand it fully without seeing a little code.

But more or less I'd recommend you to, as you dynamically generate the fields, pre-fill them with values stored upon submitting, that is (assuming you use jquery):

```
function generateFields(index) {
    $("<input/>")
          .attr("id","username_"+index)
          .val(getFieldValue("username_"+index))
          .change(function() {
                  setFieldValue("username_"+index, this.value);
          })
          .appendTo(fieldContainer);
    .
    .
    .
}

function getFieldValue(name) {
    return sessionStorage[name]||"";
}
function setFieldValue(name, value) {
    sessionStorage[name]=value||null;
}
```

The idea is, on first run, getFieldValue(whatever) would return "". Then you assign the value the user has input on change. If this code is re-executed, the fields will be filled with the previous values.

You should also clear stored values when appropriate.

Note- both sessionStorage & localStorage are basic HTML/5 features, they are available in all HTML5 browsers but obviously don't exist in (very) old browsers. 
hope it helps!

Comment: I think you're right about the sessionStorage as opposed to local. I'll def look into trying this out. In terms of whats happening to the generated fields, I'm cloning the div, incrementing it's class number and applying that to the individual inputs:                 var fnameID ='firstname' + containerNumber;
$('.emptyContainer #firstname1').attr({id: fnameID, name: fnameID}) Where the id ends up as one more than the last.

Comment: yeah the approach seems right, one caveat though, when using selectors try to do $(".emptyContainer > #firstname1") instead of $(".emptyContainer #firstname1"). The first one is very fast, while the latter is ultra slow, because the browser has to traverse the whole document trying to find an .emptyContainer anywhere before the firstname. In the first case, the selector restrict the .emptyContainer to the parent node only.

Comment: It's looking good so far. The inputs are saving on return! (Although the div is hidden when I return to the page but at least the values are saving!) Thanks so much!